# What regular expression engine does QGIS use?

Tags: qgis, regular-expression

Where can I find the documentation about QGIS regular expression engine and how to craft a pattern with it. I see the [following regex functions documented](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html)

- regexp_replace
- regexp_substr
- regexp_matches
- regexp_match

Answer (score 19, accepted):

QGIS, uses [QT's QRegularExpression.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) which is itself just [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions).

> QRegularExpression implements **Perl-compatible regular expressions**. It fully supports Unicode. For an overview of the regular expression syntax supported by QRegularExpression, please refer to the aforementioned pcrepattern(3) man page. A regular expression is made up of two things: a pattern string and a set of pattern options that change the meaning of the pattern string.

You can see the use of it in [src/core/qgsexpression.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/6ea0049b1791425a4ac7cb7ec39345a8543853fe/src/core/qgsexpression.cpp)

Note one Gotcha with the QT C++ implementation is that **you have to escape `\`**,

> Note that due to C++ literal strings rules, you must escape all backslashes inside the pattern string with another backslash:

```
// matches two digits followed by a space and a word
QRegularExpression re("\\d\\d \\w+");

// matches a backslash
QRegularExpression re2("\\\\");
```

Another but very minor non-gotcha, is

> QRegularExpression does not support all the features available in Perl-compatible regular expressions. The most notable one is the fact that **duplicated names for capturing groups are not supported**, and using them can lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a lot of rooting around to get the information I needed.  Source code may be the definitive documentation, but this information is too important not to be documented elsewhere in QGIS online documentation.

Comment: @bixb0012 np, upvote the question/answer if you found it useful. I asked and self-answered to save everyone time.