# Replacing '+' with ', ' for labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, replace

I want to replace a '+' with ', ' to label an attribute looking like "ZT10+ZT20+ZT30" to get "ZT10, ZT20, ZT30" using

```
regexp_replace("zone_nr", '+', ', ')
```

but I get an Eval Error: Invalid regular expression '+': quantifier does not follow a repeatable item.

Comment: Have you tried `replace("zone_nr", '+', ', ')`?

Comment: is using `regexp_replace()` mandatory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `+` is a special symbol to the QGis regular expression engine (it means 1 or more of the preceding character), so you need to *escape* it by putting a `\` in front of it. So you need:

```
regexp_replace("zone_nr", '\\+', ', ')
```

Comment: Backslash characters must be double escaped   `  \\ `

Comment: but only if I want a \ not if using it as an escape

Comment: @IanTurton actually, no, you need to double escape **all** backslashes, e.g. `'\\\\'` would match *one* backslash. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217404/93656) covers more. or did this change in QGIS 3.x?

Comment: You are right, I'm in java mode just now!

Answer (score 9):

Or, simply use

```
replace("zone_nr", '+', ', ')
```

as this doesn't expect a *regexp* term (it simply matches all occurences of the specified input string).

Answer (score 2):

You can input regular expression to find every single `+` like `[+]`

```
regexp_replace("zone_nr", '[+]', ', ')
```

Comment: btw., this will replace *the whole string* with `', '` if a `'+'` was found in it!

Comment: You're right I improved my answer