# Splitting string into "alphabetic" or "numeric" in QGIS 3.10.1

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, string

What are the right functions and formulas with the field calculator to delete "alphabet" or "number" inside a field?

Let me be clear. I want to be able to delete "alphabetic letters" or "numbers" inside my records (see the image). I've used `replace`, `left`, `substr` functions, but they don't make any difference between "alphabet" and "number".

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show us a sample on how the texts in the attribute table are look like.

Comment: when extracting apply: for integers use `to_int(regexp_substr("field_name", '(\\d+)'))` and for symbols `to_string(regexp_substr("field_name", '[A-Za-z]+'))`. when deleting use `regexp_replace()`instead.

Comment: @Taras, your formulas are working!!! Tank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To split your field into subfiels, i.e. "alphabetic" or "numeric" apply:

for integers:

```py
to_int(regexp_substr("field_name", '(\\d+)'))
```

that will give you `'199'` from `'199 (ME)'`

for symbols:

```py
to_string(regexp_substr("field_name", '[A-Za-z]+'))
```

that will give you `'ME'` from `'199 (ME)'`

---

**References:**

- [What regular expression engine does QGIS use?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217403/what-regular-expression-engine-does-qgis-use)
- [GitHub | QGIS > resources > function_help > json](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/resources/function_help/json)
- [PY4E - Regular Expressions (Chapter 11 Part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovZsvN67Glc)

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression to get only the numers and replace `[0]` with `[2]` to get only the alphabetic letters:

```
regexp_matches(name,'(\\d+)*(\\s+|\\W+)*(\\p{L}+)*')[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice that you are now more familiar with regex ^_^