# Replacing characters using an expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, regular-expression

What regular expression can I use to change values in a string field? I need to change the letter `B` to a symbol `-` before the digits, and digits with letter `F` to make positive.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: All values include `F` or `B` or both, right? I mean "is there like: `5_45` or just `1`?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions, you can do this with the following expression in the field calculator - see the [PCRE Regex Cheatsheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre) (that's the [regular expression engine QGIS uses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217404/88814)) [not reachable right now, [see another site](https://remram44.github.io/regex-cheatsheet/regex.html) instead for the moment and let's hope the former site will be back soon] for functions and syntax.

This solution first converts your input to an array (each element delimited with _ is considered a separate value in the array), then with a for loop using array_foreach replaces the values: first, F is replaced with an empty value '', than from this output, it replaces any string at the beginning `^(.*)`, followed by `B` at the end of the string (`$`) with a `-` followed by the element at the first positon (`\\1` - the cheatsheet above says: "\Y Match the Y'th captured group" - however, in QGIS you have to use two \ as mentioned in the context help of the expression editor) of the input:

```
array_to_string (
    array_foreach (
        string_to_array( "string", '_'),
        regexp_replace (
            regexp_replace(  @element, '^(.*)B$', '-\\1'),
            'F',
            ''
        )
    )
)
```

You can also create a virtual field to get dynamic updates when you insert new values in the first column:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for solution and links!

Answer (score 6):

One of the solutions in a long way may be the following.

```java
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        string_to_array(linecode, '_'),
        if(
            right(@element, 1) = 'F',
            substr(@element, 0, strpos(@element, 'F') - 1),
            '-' + substr(@element,0, strpos(@element, 'B') - 1)
        )
    )
)
```

How does it work:

- split the value by underscore (`_`). `->` `['6F', '45F', '29B']`
- check the last character for every `element`.
- if it is `F`, return all characters except of the last one (`F`).
- if it is not `F` (then the last character is `B`), then return all characters except of the last one (`B`) and add `-` to the beginning of `element`.  `->` `['6', '45', '-29']`
- finally, convert the array into string.  `->` `'6,45,-29'`

Comment: Thanks! A great solution.How learn to write expressions like this?It's fantastic