# Removing unwanted data in the cell of the QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, string, regular-expression, qgis-expression

How can I remove remove data after any special character in the cell using QGIS?

E.g.: `Valli Amman Mandir, Chettiyakotai`

I want only `Valli Amman Mandir` in the cell. The rest should be removed.

Comment: It would help to be more specific than "any special character."  Are numeric characters considered special?  What about punctuation characters?  Hyphens are common in names, do you mean to treat them differently than other punctuation characters?  What about symbol or separator characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this expression based on regular expressions to:

1. find the first special character - special character understood as everything else than letters from `a` to `z` (upper and lower case), number `0` to `9` and white spaces `\\s`. You could adapt the definition of "special character" by adding or removing characters.
2. delete everything starting from this special character until the end of the input string, returning just everything before it.

```
regexp_replace ("fieldname", '[^A-Za-z0-9\\s].*','')
```

[image]

---

Explanation: [`regexp_replace ()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) uses [regular expressions](https://regexone.com/): for an input string (`"fieldname"`), it matches everything that corresponds to the regex defined (see below) and replaces it with an empty string `''`.

The regex is defined as `[^A-Za-z0-9\\s].*`. This works like this:

- square brackets `[]` to define a group of characters;
- inside the brackets, several groups are defined: letters A to Z (uppercase): `A-Z`, a to z (lowercase): `a-z`, digits 0 to 9: `0-9` as well as [any white space](https://regexone.com/lesson/whitespaces) `\\s`;
- These groups are treated as "normal" characters - so to find *special* characters, we have to exclude these ones. To exclude specific characters, use the `^` (hat). With this, we match any character except letters A-z, a-z, digits 0-9 and white spaces. So this finds periods `.`, commas `,`, double points `:`, semicolons `;` etc.
- We want to get everything inside the input string starting with these special characters, so we add `.*` that matches any number (using quantifier `*`, meaning: zero or more) of characters of any kind (using the dot `.` - a wildcard that stands for any character) - so in fact everything inside the string after the special character.

Comment: But if Valli Amman Mandir is not at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @katagena OP does not mention this, they only say: " remove data after any special character". I don't know what cases you're thinking about. This solution works for any kind of string to remove everyting after the (first) special character. That's how I understood the question.

Comment: @babel To exclude specific characters, use the ^ (hat). can you please elaborate

Answer (score 5):

A solution inspired by @BenW's previous answer. I was going to comment the suggested change, but the post was taken down.

```
left("field", regexp_match("field", '[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]') -1)
```

`regexp_match` finds the position of a specified pattern, in this case the first special character* in the string (as thoroughly explained by @Babel). The `left()` function is used to keep only the characters up to the returned position. `-1` is used to shift the position over one to omit the special character from the returned string.

* *or more specifically, the first non-alphanumeric character that is not a space*

Answer (score 3):

The example given doesn't appear to be using English names.  [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=TT&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Valli%20Amman%20Mandir%2C%20Chettiyakotai&op=translate) guesses they are romanized Tamil words.  I point this out because none of the existing answers create a regular expression that recognizes a broader world than US-ASCII, well, maybe Windows-1252 or ISO/IEC 8859-15 if giving the benefit of the doubt.

According to this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217404) for [What regular expression engine does QGIS use? - Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217403/what-regular-expression-engine-does-qgis-use), "QGIS, uses [QT's QRegularExpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html). which is itself just [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)."

> QRegularExpression implements Perl-compatible regular expressions. It fully supports Unicode.

This is great news.  QGIS uses PCRE, which is a very robust regular expression engine that fully supports Unicode, so why not write Unicode regular expressions that work for the Roman alphabet as well as other alphabets, like the Tamil alphabet?

If one is going to work with PCRE regular expressions, such as in QGIS, it is good to bookmark [pcre2pattern specification - pcre.org](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html).  The **Unicode character properties** section covers most of what I use below.

As I mentioned in my comment to the question, it is important to be specific with regular expressions.  Phrases like "any special character" don't really mean anything because they can mean so many different things to so many different people.  For my expression below, I am assuming "any special character" means the Unicode "Other Punctuation" character category, and I am using `\N` instead of `\X` so to mimic the newline behavior of the `.` metacharacter.

`regexp_replace("fieldname", '\\p{Zs}*\\p{Po}+\\N*', '')`

Breaking down the regular expression:

```
\p{Zs} Unicode category:  Matches any character in the 'Space separator' Unicode category
  * Quantifier:  Match 0 or more of the preceding token
\p{Po} Unicode category:  Matches any character in the 'Other punctuation' Unicode category
  + Quantifier:  Match 1 or more of the preceding token
\N Not line break.  Matches any character that is not a line break
  * Quantifier.  Match 0 or more of the preceding token
```

Not only does the expression convert `Valli Amman Mandir, Chettiyakotai` to `Valli Amman Mandir`, but it also works with the Tamil alphabet to convert `வள்ளி அம்மன் மந்திர், செட்டியகோட்டை` to `வள்ளி அம்மன் மந்திர்`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous brilliant answers, you can use the `regex group` to capture a specific part of the string. Using the following expression, you can capture the first part of the string before the comma `,` as follows:

```
regexp_replace("Fieldname",'(\\w.+)(,)(\\s{0,1}\\w+)','\\1')
```

Where:

`Fieldname` is the name of the field from which you want to extract the text.

`(\\w.+)` is the  1st Capturing Group. the parentheses is for capturing groups `()`. The `\\w` matches any word character (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), the `.` matches any character, and the `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times.

`(,)` is the 2nd Capturing Group

`(\\s{0,1}\\w+)` is the 3rd Capturing Group. The `\\s` matches any whitespace character, and `{0,1}` matches the previous token between zero and one time.

`\\1` replaces the text in the new field with the first captured group only, which is everything before the comma `,`. In other words, select everything before the comma.

Example:

The `name` field has the strings that we want to extract the text from, and the `selected` field is a new field that we want to have the final selected text.

Applying the above expression to update the `selected` field we got the desired output:

[image]

**Update** based on [@Babel's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447803/removing-unwanted-data-in-the-cell-of-the-qgis-attribute-table/447868?noredirect=1#comment731182_447868)

The above approach removes anything after a comma, however, to remove anything after a special character, the following expression can be used:

```
regexp_replace ("name", '[^\\w.\\s+].+|[\\.\\+].+','')
```

Where:

`[^\\w.\\s+]` match any character **not** present in the list one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.

`\s` matches any whitespace character.

`\w` matches any word character

`|` means Or

`[\.\+]` Match a single character present in the list below where `\.` matches the character `.` and + matches the character `+` escaped by a backslash as they are special characters in regex.

then remove the selected texts using the `regex_replace` function.

Example (2)

[image]

Comment: This works, but only for commas, not for any other special character (OP asks about "remove data after any special character").

Comment: @Babel You are right, I was looking at the example where the comma is presented. I updated my answer to remove any text after a special character.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to work in all cases... see screenshot: the last part `sdf` appears, even if it is after the special character. If you have two spaces one after the other, also some parts before the special character will be deleted, see e.g. row 4 and after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4mht.png

Comment: @Babel thanks for your confirmation. You are right, I missed the `.` in the last `\\w+`. Now it works including some of your examples in rows 7 and 8 in the last picture :).

Comment: What about if there isn't a space after the special character?

Comment: @bixb0012 Excellent catch. I updated the answer. Now it removes any character whether there is a space or not with multiple special characters.

Comment: Sorry to still insist: `regexp_replace ("Fieldname", '[^\\w.\\s+].+','')` does not work to remove a dot `.` as special character. Why do you use `^\\w` (negation of "any alphanumeric character") instead of `\\W` (any non-alphanumeric character)?

Comment: @Babel No worries. Your comments are valuable. I updated the answer to consider special characters like `.` and `+`. I used `^\\w` to select everything except letters, which is everything after the special character(s), and replace it/them with an empty character.